# Multiple checkbox with separating submit button with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, codeigniter

Hi Thank you for checking my question. Hope you would help me. I'm having a problem. I want to separate my submit button in a checkbox. Since the button for the submit in checkbox is at the upper part of the website. Here's my code segment:
This is the code for the button. I'm using codeigniter

```
          <button name="delete" class="label label-danger" type="submit" value ="delete">Remove</button>
```

So I want everytime the button clicked the checked box will be deleted.

Here's the code for the checkbox:

```
            <?php
                $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","dbms_project");
                // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $id = $row['Customer_ID'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . form_checkbox('checkbox[]', '$id', FALSE) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Phone'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                        $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
                        $count = count($checkbox);

                        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                            $id = (int) $checkbox[$i]; // Parse your value to integer

                            if ($id > 0) { // and check if it's bigger then 0
                                mysql_query("DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id = $id");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: what happens when you run your code?

Comment: Nothing. I'm trying to figure it out what's happening. Since my goal is to have a submit button in the upper of the checkbox. Any other suggestion?

So I tried to access the button but it doesn't work. With this code below the button.

          <?php
     if (isset($_POST['delete'])) { 
    echo "Dick Butt";
      }
     
     ?>

It doesn't work.

Comment: if you echo `$_POST['delete']` does it contain anything?

Comment: it says undefined index.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the form markup (without names, if necessary)?  Is your form data being submitted in the URL as `GET` parameters?

Comment: You really should read [Codeigniter's documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html)

Comment: I don't see any Codeigniter here

Comment: if you are using Codeigniter, you need to take advantage of all its features. The biggest being the database, models, controllers.. you are not using any of these features. Learn Codeigniter, and fix your code, in the it would probably be better to use AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. Actually this is a school project that is due later. That's why I'm not using all the features. I'll fix it after I present everything.

Answer (score -1):

I have already solve the problem. It seems that I need to use a jquery function. For instance :
JQuery script.

```
            <script>
            $("#formDelete").click(function(){
            $("#formDeletion").trigger("submit");
            })
            </script>
```

The form:

```
 <form id='formDeletion' action ='remove' method='post'>
            <!--Start of calling the tables-->
            <?php
                $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","dbms_project");
                // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $id = $row['Customer_ID']; ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='selector[]' value='<?php echo $id?>'/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $id?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['First_Name'] ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['Last_Name'] ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['Address']?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['Phone'] ?> </td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                }?>
      </form>
```

the input button is the formDelete and the id of the form is formDeletion.

Thanks for the help everyone!